# .Net core ModelBinding does not Invalidate ModelState for primitive values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using .Net Core 3. I have a controller with `[ApiController]` attribute on it. So it returns BadRequest Error if Model Validation fails, automatically. But I have primitive values in my models like int, bool, and if I don't include these values in my request object, the ApiController does not produce an error in this case. But initializes these fields to default value. I want it to produce BadRequest Error. How can I do this? 
I made the fields nullable and it worked but I don't want to make them nullable. Please help me. Thanks.

Edit:

```
 public class AddEmployeeReqObject
{
    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("casino_id")]
    [Display(Name = "casino_id")]
    public long CasinoId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    [Display(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("yubico_key")]
    [Display(Name = "yubico_key")]
    public string YubicoKey { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("is_manager")]
    [Display(Name = "is_manager")]
    public bool IsManager { get; set; }
}
```

Here IsManager and CasinoId are initialized by default with false and 0.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Yes they do and I've updated the question.

Comment: making them nullable is the suggested approach for value types

Answer (score 0):

You should use BindRequiredAttribute instead of RequiredAttribute. RequiredAttribute works perfect for nullable-types, but for non-nullable it has no effect. For example for int the default value is 0 and the property can never be null. Even if the client submits a request where the property is completely missing, the model instance would have a value 0.

BindRequiredAttribute comes to action!

It works the same way as RequiredAttribute, except it mandates that the value comes from the request – so it not only rejects null values, but also “unbound” values.

For examples visit: https://www.strathweb.com/2017/12/required-and-bindrequired-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

Comment: I've tried BindRequired but it does not work as well.

Comment: `BindRequiredAttribute` is [only applicable for "non-body" parameters](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/893#issuecomment-425123976).

Answer (score 0):

> I don’t know why you both set the default value for the fields, but
>   also want to judge it's default value as null and verify as an error.

While verifying `ModelState.IsValid`, you can determine whether the two fields of the model are the default values you set. If yes, then fail the verification and return BadRequest Error.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test(AddEmployeeReqObject obj)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid && obj.CasinoId != 0 && obj.IsManager)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes this is also an option but I did not wanted to do this validation myself that was the main point.

Comment: @honey_ramgarhia, I think that if you must assign default values to these fields, it is impossible to automatically verify as false.

Answer (score 0):

int and bool variables cannot be null so to check them you have to:

1. make them nullable and test if they are null
     or
2. set the bool field  true (precheck the checkbox or sth) and set the int to a negative       value